# How do let, require, and prototype work together to make objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Specifically, I'm looking at the [Adblock](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluscore/blob/master/lib/matcher.js) javascript codebase. Several parts to this:

1) There's a line in there

`let {Filter, RegExpFilter, WhitelistFilter} = require("filterClasses");`

I understand that `let` is used to create block-scoped variables, but what are the brackets doing?

2) A little further down in the code is:

```
function Matcher()
{
  this.clear();
}
exports.Matcher = Matcher;

Matcher.prototype = {
    filterByKeyword = null, //...variables
    clear: function() {
        //sample function, lots more
    },
    myfunc : function() {
        return "blah blah";
    }
}
```

`module.exports` makes functions and properties inside it available, but is `exports.Matcher = Matcher` the same thing? I want to create a Matcher object and use the variables & functions inside of it. I tried emulating the style (in a separate js file) via

```
let {Matcher} = require("matcher");
function testfunc() {
    let matcher = new Matcher();
    console.log(matcher.myfunc());
}
```

and then using node in the terminal with `node --harmony test.js`.

But it throws an `UnexpectedToken` error at the `let {}` block. I'm not sure if I'm creating the object correctly or what exactly is going on. Any ideas on how to start unraveling this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is a so called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that can be used to conveniently extract data from objects to variables.

The second block is describing a module that exposes the class `Matcher`. A very good article on `module.exports`/`exports.xxx` is [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

Your code itself looks perfectly fine according to ES2015 specification. However you should take care when using ES2015 features in node.js and carefully read the [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/):

1. `let` is only working in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)
2. `--harmony_destructuring` is a *in progress* feature, therefore you should not rely on it because it may have some bugs. I recommend using some ES2015 compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) if you want to make use of ES2015 features

Comment: Regarding `exports.Matcher = Matcher`, doesn't that mean there needs to be a line that explicitly sets `var exports = module.exports `? No such line exists in the current codebase, though.

Comment: No, you do not have to do this, `exports` and `module.exports` reference to the same object implicitly. The article I linked says "Imagine that this line of code exists as the first line of code", you might have misread that :)

Comment: OH. I guess my imagination isn't very good. :P Anyway, I managed to get babel up and running after quite a bit of trial and error (for posterity, the command I'm using is `./node_modules/.bin/babel-node myfile.js`, because just babel-node gives me `directory not found` errors). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). In the second instance `exports.Matcher` simply defines the object that the module exports to consumers.

Comment: So would I be able to run it using node on my system, or is there another interpreter I should be using? Right now it keeps throwing errors at the `let` block.